# GitHub Repository search using partial or begins-with

Tags: github

I would like to do a code search in a collection of repositories.  I would like to restrict my search using a pattern or naming convention in the repository name.

1) I can limit my search by the organization.
Example: "user:google"

2) I can search a single repository directly.
Example: "repo:google/devtoolsExtended test"

So, is it possible to search all repositories that begin with a pattern?
Equivalent to: "repo:google/dev* test"

Comment: Using the API? Or GitHub search itself?

Comment: GitHub search, Using the get hub web interface.    I'm sorry, I should have been specific.

Answer (score 0):

In order to search for repositories all you need to do is just type in your query, like the following:

https://github.com/search?q=foo

This finds repos such as `FooTable` and `foodme` as well, as if we searched for `foo*`. If you want to limit your search to the repository name only, use `in:name`, which results in:

https://github.com/search?q=foo+in%3Aname&type=Repositories

There's no explicit method of searching by `begins with` or using wildcards, but results for those kinds of searches appear as well.

Sources:

- GitHub Help: [Searching repositories](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/)

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer is perfect for finding all the repositories that have the pattern.  Now, can this be combined with a code search?  I would like to find a ClassName only searching in repositories with this name pattern.